# Typescript return SQL Server connection variable

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, connection

I am using a method to return SQL Server connection variable.

```
const sql = require('mssql');

/* sql configuration */
var config = {
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    server: '***',
    database: '***',
    port: '***',
    multipleStatements: true,
    timezone: '+00:00'
};

 function getRequest(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
        sql.close()    
        sql.connect(config, function (err:any) {            
                if (err) reject(err); 
            var sqlrequest = new sql.Request();  
            //console.log(sqlrequest);          
            resolve(sqlrequest);    
        });       
    });
}
```

I am calling the connection by below code. but this is not working, the process is not hitting section one. Could any one help me thank you.

```
getRequest().then(function(sqlrequest:any) {
   //not hitting into this section --section 1 
   sqlrequest.input('ReturnValue',0);
   sqlrequest.output('ReturnValue',sql.Int);
   sqlrequest.execute('SaveHl7File')
.then(function(recordsets:any, err:any) {
  console.log([recordsets0);
}
```

Comment: Doe it hit the `resolve(sqlrequest);` line? (it looks like you had a console.log)

Comment: I solved it, I didn't made sequential callback. Now its fine. tq. @styfle

Comment: Please post your answer below so that others with a similar problem can see how you resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: @chandoo can you share how you handled this scenario? I face this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847239/cypress-task-undefined-even-though-the-promise-is-returned)